# How I can change the colour for when the switch is toggled?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I got this code online, I'm confused as to how I can get the background colour to change when the button is toggled. How would I get it to change colour when the html containers are .

```css
:root {
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  --line-color: hsl(234, 12%, 35%);
  --active-color: hsl(234, 100%, 98%);
  --inactive-color: hsl(234, 20%, 68%);
  --body-color: hsl(189, 49%, 87%);
  --background-colour: hsl(189, 84%, 14%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
}

.toggle__content {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.toggle__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-block: .5rem;
}

.toggle__check {
  display: none;
}

.toggle__rail {
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: var(--line-color);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.toggle__circle {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px var(--inactive-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: transform .4s, box-shadow .4s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.toggle__border {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -4px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: transform .4s;
}


/* Toggle animation effects */

.toggle__check:checked~.toggle__rail .toggle__circle {
  transform: translateX(28px);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 12px var(--active-color);
}

.toggle__check:checked~.toggle__rail .toggle__border {
  transform: translateX(28px);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle__content">
  <label class="toggle__label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle__check">

        <div class="toggle__rail">
            <span class="toggle__circle"></span>
            <span class="toggle__border"></span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```

I want to change it from --body-color: hsl(189, 84%, 14%) to --background-colour: hsl(189, 84%, 14%) when the switch is toggled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change is to simply listen for the `input` (or `change` if you prefer) event, and then toggle a class on the `<body>` element based on the checked/unchecked state of the `<input>` as below, with explanatory comments in the code:

```js
// here we use document.querySelector() to get the first element on the page that
// matches the supplied CSS selector; note that if you have multiple matching
// elements you'll need to use document.querySelectorAll(), and then use a loop of
// some kind to bind an event to each element (also this should also have been stated
// in your question):
document.querySelector('.toggle__check')
  // we then use EventTarget.addEventListener() to bind the anonymous Arrow function
  // as the event-handler of the 'input' event fired on the element:
  .addEventListener('input',
    // here we're using an Arrow function, as we have no requirement to use "this",
    // and we pass in a reference to the Event Object (here called "evt", but that's
    // a user-defined name, you can call it what you prefer) passed from the
    // EventTarget.addEventListener() method:
    // within the function body:
      //  we find the <body> element (via document.body):
    (evt) => document.body
      // we utilise the Element.classList API:
      .classList
      // calling the toggle() method, and supply a class-name to add, or remove,
      // if the evaluation is true (or truthy) the class-name is added, and if
      // false (or falsey) it's removed.
      // within the assessment we retrieve the Event.currentTarget property-value
      // which returns the element to which the function was bound (the <input>)
      // and the 'checked' property of that Element returns a Boolean value,
      // true if it's checked and false if it's not checked:
      .toggle('alt-color', true === evt.currentTarget.checked));
```

```css
:root {
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  /*Color mode HSL(hue, saturation, lightness)*/
  
  /* purely as an aside, I've changed your color syntax to use
     CSS Colors Level 4 syntax, in which the original
     "hsl(234, 12%, 35%) can be written as a space-separated
     list of values hsl(<hue> <saturation> <lightness>), and may
     include opacity: hsl(<hue> <saturation> <lightness> / <alpha>)
     without having to specify hsla(); while I've deliberately
     added the 'deg' unit to the initial value, that's implied if
     the unit is absent and not necessary to specify; but it is
     a personal preference of my own. */
  --line-color: hsl(234deg 12% 35%);
  --active-color: hsl(234deg 100% 98%);
  --inactive-color: hsl(234deg 20% 68%);
  --body-color: hsl(189deg 49% 87%);
  --background-colour: hsl(189deg 84% 14%);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  /* here we add a transition, in order that the background-color
     transitions between different colour-values: */
  transition: background-color 300ms linear;
}

/* here we specify a different background-color for the
   <body> element if it has the class-name of 'alt-color': */
body.alt-color {
  /* as an aside, I strongly suggest that you use the same
     spelling of "colour" throughout your CSS; it's up to
     you how you spell it (color, colour, or even kolour)
     would all be perfectly valid but switching between
     spellings (above you have '--body-color' and here you
     have '--background-colour') increases the likelihood
     of unexpected errors/failures: */
  background-color: var(--background-colour);
}

.toggle__content {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.toggle__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-block: .5rem;
}

.toggle__check {
  display: none;
}

.toggle__rail {
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: var(--line-color);
  border-radius: 2rem;
}

.toggle__circle {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px var(--inactive-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: transform .4s, box-shadow .4s;
  z-index: 2;
}

.toggle__border {
  position: absolute;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -4px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  transition: transform .4s;
}


/* Toggle animation effects */

.toggle__check:checked~.toggle__rail .toggle__circle {
  transform: translateX(28px);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 12px var(--active-color);
}

.toggle__check:checked~.toggle__rail .toggle__border {
  transform: translateX(28px);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle__content">
  <label class="toggle__label">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle__check">

        <div class="toggle__rail">
            <span class="toggle__circle"></span>
            <span class="toggle__border"></span>
        </div>
    </label>
</div>
```